# Java: Sieve of Eratosthenes: Array as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My goal is to Turn off, or set to false, all array spots that are not prime. Array is provided as a parameter.

```
public static boolean[] sieveOfEratosthenes(boolean [] a){

    int increment= 2;

    for(int n = 0; n < 9; n++){
        for(int i = increment; i < a.length; i += increment){
            a[i] = false;
        }
        increment += 1;
    }   
    a[2] = true;
    a[3] = true;
    a[5] = true;
    a[7] = true;
    return a;
}
```

Code works fine, I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way than using:

```
a[2] = true;
a[3] = true;
a[5] = true;
a[7] = true;
```

to reset those array items as true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by definition all spots that are not `false` should be `true`, correct? So initialize the entire array to `true`, then set the positions that can't be prime to `false`.

Comment: It is a homework assignment, I am not able to alter the array, and they are all set to true. I am assuming the array provided is full of an array of number from 0-*infinity*

Comment: @HunterMcMillen wouldn't it be less operations to just set true to true after initializing to false?? Many more primes than not primes.

Comment: You might want to start by reading about the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: When it's homework, please tag as such.

Comment: @pb2q you misread the OP code.

Comment: @TylerHeiks no. What's the difference in setting items to false after initializing to true? We mark non-primes, true or false, whatever - we still mark non-primes. That's the essence of the Sieve of E. If you try to mark primes, you must test them somehow, each one separately, independently, usually by trial division, and that's much less efficient. Here we just count up from a prime and thus find all its multiples at once. No testing. So marking non-primes is much better.

Comment: @WillNess you misunderstood me. I don't want him to test the primes and im not telling him to do it differently, I want him to do it like sieve of E but when marking i want him to mark the primes. You which are the primes because they are the ones you wouldn't have marked when you mark the non-primes...
ex:

Comment: ex: list of ten that starts
T T T T T T T T T T and you use Sieve of E to mark F T T F T F T F F
When you get to 1000's or millions then you will be making much less reassignments

Comment: if my list of 10 is from 700 - 709 starting with  
F F F F F F F F F F then it becomes F T F F F F F F F T which is much less changes and I still use the more efficient SOE

Comment: @TylerHeiks what I'm saying is, in Sieve of E, we mark non-primes. There is no way to mark primes in sieve of E. We don't know what will be found *between the marked composites* until we have marked *all the composites*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do this is to start your loop at iteration * 2. So your loop looks like this

```
int increment= 2;

for(int n = 0; n < 9; n++){
    for(int i = increment*2; i < a.length; i += increment){
        a[i] = false;
    }
    increment += 1;
}
```

This way you skip the first one.

Second modify your outer loop so that it ignores values that are already false because its prime factors took care of its products.
Now your loop looks like this

```
int increment= 2;

for(int n = 0; n < 9; n++){
    if(a[increment]) {
      for(int i = increment*2; i < a.length; i += increment){
          a[i] = false;
      }
      increment += 1;
    }
}
```

Third to handle any size array loop over your array for your increment value

```
int count = a.length;

for(int increment = 2; increment < count; increment++){
    if(a[increment]) {
      for(int i = increment*2; i < count; i += increment){
          a[i] = false;
      }          
    }
}
```

This current loop assumes one and zero are considered prime. So set `a[0] = a[1] = false;` to reflect the fact that 0 and 1 are not prime.

Comment: An even better way to do this is to start your loop at `int i = increment * increment`, and increase by `i += 2*increment` for all *odd* increments. Then also change last loop's stop condition to `for(...; increment <= count/increment; ...)`. I think you've got a typo right in the ending sentence (missing *"not"* there). Fixed it for you! :)